# Error Property 'activo' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent' Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy ejecutando el comando `ng run build` en mi proyecto de angular6 y obtengo el siguiente error:

> ERROR in src\app\sidebar\sidebar.component.html(1,68): : Property 'activo' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'.

Este es el archivo **.html** en donde se encuentra el error...
Pd. ejecutar el `ng serve -o` se genera normalmente y puedo realizar lo que deseo tranquilamente solo me muestra este error cuando escribo el comando `ng build -prod`

```
<button  type="button" id="boton1" class="btn btn-dark nav-item  " [ngClass]="{'d-none':activo=='primero'}" [ngClass]="{'d-block':activo=='segundo'}" (click)="activo='primero'">
        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
    </button>
    <button  type="button" id="boton2" class="btn btn-success nav-item d-none" [ngClass]="{'d-block':activo=='primero'}" [ngClass]="{'d-none':activo=='segundo'}"  (click)="activo='segundo'" >
        <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
    </button>
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- ACA COMIENZA EL SIDEBAR -->
        <!-- ACA COMIENZA EL HEADER DEL SIDEBAR-->
        <nav id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{'active':activo=='primero'}" >
            <div  class="sidebar-header">
                <div align='center' class="sidebar-header-grey"> 

                    <a href="http://globalr.net/site/"  class="simple-text " >
                        <img  class="gris":hover src="assets/GR.png" width="130" height="50" >
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>

          <!-- ACA TERMINA EL HEADER DEL SIDEBAR-->
            <!-- ACA COMIENZA EL CONTENIDO DEL SIDEBAR -->

            <ul  class="list-unstyled components ">
                    <p><a [routerLink]="['/Gestionar2', {outlets: {'cero': ['hijo0']}} ]">Gestion de Proyecto</a></p>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" >Herramientas</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a [routerLink]="['/Crear', {outlets: {'uno': ['hijo']}} ]">Crear</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a [routerLink]="['/Modificar', {outlets: {'dos': ['hijo2']}} ]" >Modificar</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" >Eliminar</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul> 
                    </ul>

        </nav>
        <!-- ACA TERMINA EL SIDEBAR -->

<div id="content">
    <!-- ACA COMIENZA EL NAVBAR -->
    <!-- ACA TERMINA EL NAVBAR-->
    <!-- ACA COMIENZA CONTENIDO -->

    <div  [ngClass]="{'contraer':activo=='primero'}" >
        <router-outlet name="cero"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="uno"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="dos"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="tres"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="cuatro"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="cinco"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="seis"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <!-- ACA TERMINA EL CONTENIDO--> 
</div>
</div>
```

Aca esta el . ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

currentUrl:string;

  constructor(private router: Router) { 
    router.events.subscribe((_: NavigationEnd)=>{
      if(!!_.url){
        this.currentUrl=_.url
      }
    }
  );

  }


  cero: boolean=true;
  uno: boolean=true;
  dos: boolean=true; 
  tres: boolean=true ;
  cuatro: boolean; 
  cinco: boolean; 
  seis: boolean; 
  siete: boolean; 
  ocho: boolean; 
  nueve: boolean ;
  diez:boolean=true ;
  once: boolean ;
  doce:boolean ;

  ngOnInit() {

  }



  titulo1():void{


    this.cero = false;
    this.uno = false;
    this.dos = false;
    this.tres = false;
    this.diez = false;
    this.doce = true;

}
titulo2():void{

  this.uno = false;
  this.dos = false;
  this.tres = false;
  this.diez = false;
  this.cuatro = true;
  this.cinco = true;
  this.seis = true;
  this.siete = true;
  this.ocho = true;
  this.nueve = true;
  this.once = true;

}

cambiartitulo():void{


  this.cero = false;
  this.cuatro = false;
  this.cinco = false;
  this.seis = false;
  this.siete = false;
  this.ocho = false;
  this.nueve = false;
  this.once = false;
  this.doce = true;
}
cambiartitulo1():void{


  this.cero = false;
  this.cuatro = false;
  this.cinco = false;
  this.seis = false;
  this.siete = false;
  this.ocho = false;
  this.nueve = false;
  this.once = false;
  this.diez = true;
  this.doce = true;
}
cambiartitulo2():void{


  this.cero = false;
  this.cuatro = false;
  this.cinco = false;
  this.seis = false;
  this.siete = false;
  this.ocho = false;
  this.nueve = false;
  this.once = false;
  this.doce = true;
}
cambiartitulo3():void{


  this.cero = false;
  this.cuatro = false;
  this.cinco = false;
  this.seis = false;
  this.siete = false;
  this.ocho = false;
  this.nueve = false;
  this.once = false;
  this.doce = true;
}



}
```

y como ese tengo más del mismo tipo, por ejemplo:

> src\app\login\login.component.html(2,9): : Property 'title' does not
>   exist on type 'LoginComponent'.

```
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <h1>
          Welcome to {{ title }}!
        </h1>
        <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <form action="submit">
                Usuario <input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="Id"><br>
                 Contraseña <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="*******"><br>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button [routerLink]="['/Gestionar2', {outlets: {'cero': ['hijo0']}} ]" class="btn">ingresar</button>
```

> Otro mas 
>   src\app\crearproyecto\crearproyecto.component.html(66,135)::Property
>   'cambio' does not exist on type 'CrearproyectoComponent'.

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light nav-top fixed-top nav-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h4 style="padding-top: 15px" class="title text-muted">Registro de Proyecto</h4>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="content" align="center">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                        <div class="header" style="padding:15px">
                          <h4 class="title">Registro de proyecto</h4>
                          <p class="category text-muted">Por favor, Complete todos los campos</p>
                        </div>
              <div class="container">
                  <form>
                      <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="Nombre">Nombre del Proyecto</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NombreP" placeholder="Nombre" required [(ngModel)]="model.NombreP" name="NombreP" maxlength="40" size="20">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="ClienteP">Cliente</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del cliente" id="ClienteP" required [(ngModel)]="model.ClienteP" name="ClienteP" maxlength="20" size="20">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="AdminP">Administrador del Proyecto</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AdminP" required [(ngModel)]="model.AdminP" placeholder="Nombre del Administrador" name="AdminP" maxlength="40" size="20">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="CodigoP">Codigo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CodigoP"  placeholder="Ingrese número USSD/SMS " required [(ngModel)]="model.CodigoP" name="CodigoP" maxlength="40">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-3 ">
                        <label for="FechaIP">Fecha de Inicio</label>
                        <input type="date" min="2018-08-30" class="form-control btn-outline-secondary"  style="border-color:rgba(165, 157, 157, 0.664)" id="FechaIP" required>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group col-md-3 ">
                        <label for="FechaCP">Fecha de Culminacion</label>
                        <input type="date" min="2018-08-30" class="form-control btn-outline-secondary"   style="border-color:rgba(165, 157, 157, 0.664)" id="FechaCP" required>
                      </div>


                      <div class="form-group col-md-2 ">
                        <label>Plataforma</label><br/>
                        <select class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="border-color:rgba(165, 157, 157, 0.664)">          
                            <option value="0">USSD</option>
                            <option value="1">SMS</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-bottom: 15px">

                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrar</button>
                      &nbsp;
                      <a [routerLink]="['/Gestionar2', {outlets: {'cero': ['hijo0']}} ]"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="cambio()">Volver</button></a>

                    </div>

                    </form>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <nav id="navbar2" class="navbar fixed-bottom nav-bot navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pagina Principal <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <p class="copyright ">
              &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> <a href="http://globalr.net/site/">2018 Global Resources</a>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Creo que el error es bastante descriptivo: se queja de que no hay una propiedad `activo` en la clase `SidebarComponent` (seguramente en el fichero `sidebar.component.ts`). Y algo similar pasa con LoginComponent. Deberías poner en la pregunta el código de esas dos clases

Comment: Vale soy nuevo con angular y de verdad no entiendo porque dice q no existe, ahi añadi el el codigo del sidebar.component.ts a ver si tu puedes verlo... tambien añadi el .html del login y el de crearproyecto

Comment: debes definir las variables que utilizas, por eso el error

Comment: las puedo definir en el mismo .html? o debe ser en el .ts??

Comment: en el .ts para poder ser utilizado en el html

Comment: okey dejame intentarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta la dio JackNavaRow,en efecto, se debia de definir las variables en .ts, gracias

Comment: si esa respuesta solucionó tu problema marcala como aceptada y evita poner comentarios como respuestas

Comment: pues noc como puedo marcar al comentario como aceptada, solo se marcar las q son respuestas :l

Comment: lo ideal es que digas una solucion general de como lo solucionastes  y al dia siguiente marques tu respuesta como aceptada!